# Keybinding a JPanel from a seperate controller class

Tags: java, swing, key-bindings

So I'm trying to implement Pacman in Java for my CMPE Java course. I heard about design patterns somewhere and decided that MVC(Model-View-Controller) is the way to go.
So I made a controller class, heres a shaved version of it(original has the same functions as below repeated for the other keys):

```
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.KeyEvent;
import javax.swing.AbstractAction;
import javax.swing.Action;
import javax.swing.ActionMap;
import javax.swing.InputMap;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.KeyStroke;

public class controller {
    public class movepac extends AbstractAction{
        private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
        movepac(String a){super(a);}
        @Override
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            Direction dirtemp=Direction.RIGHT;
            // TODO direction controller method not working :(
            switch(Action.NAME) {
            case "A":

            dirtemp=Direction.LEFT;

            screen.setpac1dir(dirtemp); 

            break;

            case "VK_LEFT":
            dirtemp=Direction.LEFT;screen.setpac2dir(dirtemp); break;
                }
            }
        //end of movepac
        }
    public void mapgamekeys(JPanel a){
        InputMap iMap=a.getInputMap();
        ActionMap aMap=a.getActionMap();            
        Action act= new movepac("A");           
        iMap.put(KeyStroke.getKeyStroke(KeyEvent.VK_A,0), "A");
        aMap.put("A",act);

        act= new movepac("VK_LEFT");
        iMap.put(KeyStroke.getKeyStroke(KeyEvent.VK_LEFT,0), "VK_LEFT");
        aMap.put("VK_LEFT",act);

        a.setInputMap(0,iMap);
        a.setActionMap(aMap);
    }               
}
```

The JPanel in the mapgamekeys method is then called from my view class, named "screen":

```
    import java.awt.Color;
    import javax.swing.ImageIcon;
    import javax.swing.JFrame;
    import javax.swing.JLabel;
    import javax.swing.JPanel;


    public class screen{
//controller instance created in screen class
        controller packeys= new controller();
        static pacman pl1= new pacman(250.0,150.0);
        static pacman pl2=new pacman(450.0,150.0);
        ImageIcon pac1I= new ImageIcon(pl1.pactest.getScaledInstance(50, 50, 0));
        ImageIcon pac2I= new ImageIcon(pl2.pactest.getScaledInstance(50, 50, 0));
        JFrame fr = new JFrame("Pac Test");
        JPanel pan1 = new JPanel();
        JLabel pac1 = new JLabel(pac1I);
        JLabel pac2 = new JLabel(pac2I);

        public screen() {
            fr.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.DISPOSE_ON_CLOSE);
            fr.setSize(800,600);
            fr.add(pan1);
            fr.setVisible(true);
            fr.setResizable(false);

            pac1.setBounds((int)Math.round(pl1.pacx), (int)Math.round(pl1.pacy), 50, 50);
            pac2.setBounds((int)Math.round(pl2.pacx), (int)Math.round(pl2.pacy), 50, 50);

            pan1.setSize(800,600);
            pan1.setLayout(null);
            pan1.setBackground(Color.GRAY);
            pan1.add(pac1);
            pan1.add(pac2);
            pan1.setVisible(true);
            pan1.setFocusable(true);

     //  controller class mapgamekeys method called here with param pan1 (my JPanel)
               packeys.mapgamekeys(pan1);
            }
            public void update(double delta) {
                pl1.move(delta);
                pl2.move(delta);
                }
            public void render() {
                 pac1.setBounds((int)Math.round(pl1.pacx), (int)Math.round(pl1.pacy), 50, 50);
                 pac2.setBounds((int)Math.round(pl2.pacx), (int)Math.round(pl2.pacy), 50, 50);
                  pac1.repaint();
                  pac2.repaint();       
            }
            public static pacman getpac1() {
                return pl1;
            }
            public static pacman getpac2() {
                return pl2;
            }
            public static void setpac1dir(Direction dirtemp) {
                screen.pl1.pacDir=dirtemp;
            }
            public static void setpac2dir(Direction dirtemp) {
                screen.pl2.pacDir=dirtemp;
            }
        }
```

So the problem I'm encountering is that the game isn't actually changing the Direction enum attribute of the pacman class. Instead, both "Pacmen" are just moving right until they're off the screen. I tried manually setting their directions after a timer delay to test, and that works, and they do move in whatever Direction is indicated by their Direction attribute, however using the WASD or arrow keys does nothing.
 I dont understand what I'm doing wrong. I'm passing the JPanel to the controller class and passing it back(I think). Actually, I'm not sure that mapgamekeys() is passing the inputMap and actionMap back to my JPanel. How do I get it to work? At first I suspected that the 0 modifier for my KeyEvents is the problem, but now I just have no idea.

This is just a mockup of the final game to work on understanding how to move objects across a screen, but I was hoping I'd at least be able to get a few images to move across a screen! lol

Comment: 1) Class names should start with an upper case character. Have you ever seen a class in the JDK that doesn't? Learn by example and follow the Java conventions. 2)  Usage of static variables and methods indicates a design problem. 3) You haven't even posted your "Pacman" class so we have no idea what it is doing. 4) you can check out [Motion Using the Keyboard](https://tips4java.wordpress.com/2013/06/09/motion-using-the-keyboard/) for a working example of Key Bindings

Comment: Thanks for the response, however 
1) honestly the first time i didnt follow convention. On a mockup that was meant for my eyes only
2) I'm aware of this, static wasnt my first choice but again, its a mockup and it works for now
3) the Pacman class works, and is irrelevant here. It stores a few attributes and increments the X and Y position every tick based on its stored Direction enum. Simple stuff
4) I've read your article as well as the 4 or 5 others I read before even attempting to write my own keybindings. The problem is that I HAVE an Action, Keystroke, actionMap and InputMap >>

Comment: << and all 4 of these are present and using (I hope) the proper syntax in the mapgamekeys method. However, the JPanel is not getting the updated ActionMap and InputMap objects

Comment: I'm pretty sure the problem is that my method is setting the inputMap and actionMap of the JPanel instance that i passed as a parameter instead of the JPanel in the other class that I want it to be setting. I'm just unsure of how to pass the updated Maps back to the Screen class. Any help would be appreciated

Comment: 1) and yet is it not for your eyes only. 2) it doesn't work or you wouldn't be asking a question. Until a problem is solved you don't know what may be the cause. Therefore proper coding should be followed to eliminate possible problems. 3) until a problem is solved you don't know what is relevant. If it isn't the problem then don't post the code. You should post an [mre] which contains only the relevant code. 4) and yet your InputMap is different than mine. The panel doesn't have focus so it doesn't receive the KeyStroke is the best guess I can give.

Comment: But.. but you said KeyBindings dont need focus to work sichejcje  I'll ask my CMPE teacher in the morning and get back to this. I'm thinking of just having Controller extendJPanel, using a this reference and calling it a day

Comment: *but you said KeyBindings dont need focus to work* - correct, if you use the proper `InputMap`. You said you read the link I provided, so why are you using a different InputMap? i also told you above "your InputMap is different than mine". Did you not also read the tutorial link on "Key Bindings" to see what the differences in the InputMap are?

Comment: Hey! So I figured it out on my own a few days later. I dont know WHY but in my ActionPerformed method switching out Action.NAME for a local String i had named "name" made it work. I changed nothing else about the code. Any idea why Action.NAME didnt work as a param for my switch case?

Comment: *Any idea why Action.NAME didnt work as a param for my switch case?* - did you ever do a System.out.println(Action.Name) to see what the value is? I would suggest you should be using: `e.getActionCommand()`. Also, maintain you are still using the wrong InputMap.

Comment: Ahh I see what you mean, I rewrote my own code wrong here, its using this command to get InputMap: `
 InputMap iMap=this.getInputMap(JComponent.WHEN_IN_FOCUSED_WINDOW); `